# Common way to display list of accounts

Tags: android

I need to display a list of accounts that is returned by `AccountManager.getAccountsByType()` so user can select an account should he has more than one available.

I believe this could be achieved using a `ListView`, but is this the best way to do it or should I go through another path? Maybe some kind of dialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds faintly like a question for https://ux.stackexchange.com!

But yes, an alert dialog seems like a decent choice. The official docs describe how to do this:
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

Answer (score 0):

`AccountManager` already has an activity for displaying an account chooser.  You can invoke it with `AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent()`.

Check the docs: [newChooseAccountIntent | Activity | Android developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#newChooseAccountIntent(android.accounts.Account,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.accounts.Account%3E,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.Bundle))